# Reload or not reload google adsense page?

Tags: seo, ads, adsense

i have a main page where i have a service, the user can enter a text and the text is processed to have to user a response.

I can do it by two ways, reloading the page with http post method in a form or with ajax(laravel livewire) to no reload the page.

The question is, i have google adsense in this page, is better to reload the page in every user request when the user send the form to serve more ads or is better proccess with ajax the form and not reload the ads.

**With ajax:**
The user enter in page and send the form, only i print 1 time the ad, if the user send 5 times the form, only i showed 1 ad.

**With http form request:**
The user enter in page and if the user send the form, the page is reloaded because the user send by POST method the form, if the user send the request 5 times, the ad is showed 5 times.

I don't know if the CPC will go down because many impressions are made in the event that the page is reloaded when the user submits the form.

**¿What do you think that is better to get the best earnings?**

Comment: From the seo tag: SEO questions are off-topic. Only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on Stack Overflow. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on Webmasters.SE at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com. If someone has directed you here to read this warning, go back and delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

Reloading a page on Google AdSense can cause the ad units on that page to refresh, potentially resulting in new ads being displayed. However, reloading a page too frequently can negatively impact the user experience and may result in lower ad revenue.

It is generally not recommended to reload pages on Google AdSense too frequently, as it can lead to lower ad revenue and increased bounce rates. If you want to refresh the ads, you can use the async feature of Adsense which will refresh the ads without reloading the entire page.

Additionally, Google AdSense has a policy against automatically refreshing pages in order to increase ad impressions. This is considered to be a violation of their policies and can result in your account being terminated.

It is better to avoid reloading Adsense pages unless it's really necessary, and if you really have to do it, make sure you are doing it in a way that is not against Adsense policies.